# Unlimited levels of hierarchy in SQL table - PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, architecture

I am looking for a way to store and handle unlimited level of hierarchy for various organisations/entities stored in my DB. For example, instead of having just one parent and one child organisation (e.g. 2 levels of hierarchy) and just one-to-many relationship as allowed by self-join (e.g. having another column called parent referring to the IDs of the same table), I want to be able to have as many levels of hierarchy as possible and as many connections as possible.

Supposing I have an organisation table such as the following:

| ID | Name | Other Non-related data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 | NULL |
| 2 | Test2 | NULL |
| 3 | Test3 | something |
| 4 | Test4 | something else |
| 5 | Test5 | etc |

I am considering the following solution; for each table that I need this I can add another table named originalTable_hierarchy which refers to the organisation table in both columns and make it look like this:

| ID | Parent ID | ChildID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 |

From this table I can tell that 1 is parent to 2, 2 is parent to 4, 3 is parent to 1, 3 is also parent to 2, 2 is also parent to 3.

The restrictions I can think of are not to have the same ParentID and ChildID (e.g. a tuple like (3,3)) and not to have a record that puts them into the opposite order (e.g. if I have the (2,3) tuple, I can't also have (3,2))

Is this the correct solution for multiple organisations and suborganisations I might have later on? Users will have to navigate through them easily back and forth. If users decide to split one organisation into many, does this solution suffice? What else should I consider (extra or missing perks) when doing this instead of a traditional self-join or a certain number of tables for certain levels of hierarchy (e.g. organisaion table and suborganisation table)? Also, can you impose restrictions on certain records, so that no more childs of a certain parent can be created? Or to report on all the childs of an original parent?

Please feel free to also instruct on where to read more about this. Any relevant resources are welcome.

Comment: Look up recursive CTE queries. I think that you are on the right track.

Comment: The second table essentially models the edges of the graph. If in your case each node can only have a single parent [at most], then you could store the `parent_id` in the node itself, and get rid of the second table.

Comment: Which I believe it means a self-join in the organisation table, allowing me only a one-to-many relationship, is that correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

Comment: Thank you philipxy, I have checked that, but the actual code provided by Belayer was what I needed.  However, I want to learn more ways to model my data, because there might be versatile needs in the future. Do you have any suggestions for me on where to study more about these? Would graph databases be desirable instead of relational?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a single table as *having just one parent and one child* allows an unlimited (theoretical anyway) levels in the hierarchy. You do this by reversing the relationship so that the `Child` references the `Parent`. (Your table has the `Parent` referencing the `Child`). This results in allowing a child, at any level, also being a parent. This can be chained as far as needed.

```
create table organization ( id         integer primary key
                          , name       text
                          , parent_id  integer references organization(id) 
                          , constraint parent_not_self check (parent_id <> id) 
                          ) ;
                         
create unique index organization_not__mirrored  
       on organization( least(id,parent_id), greatest(id,parent_id) );
```

The check constraint enforces you first restriction and the unique index the second.
The following query shows the full hierarchy, along with the full path and the level.

```
with recursive hier(parent_id, child_id, path, level) as 
     ( select id, parent_id, id::text, 1 
         from organization 
        where parent_id is null 
       union all 
       select o.id, o.parent_id,h.path || '->' ||o.id::text,h.level+1 
         from organization o 
         join hier        h
           on (o.parent_id = h.parent_id)
     ) 
select * from hier;
```

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9ba4303db804a0c7ca220ee5d897d891).

Comment: Thank you Belayer for this wonderfully presented answer. Can you make a bit more indications on how this would look like if I wanted to allow a child to have multiple parents? I would in fact want to learn more about how to model my data in any way I want. Do you have any suggestions on where to read more about this?